# Displacement map based 3d effect on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to make an app which use displacement map for 3d effect. In Flash it can be done using displacement filter like shown here: http://flashflex.com/pixel-bender-displacement-map-fakes-3d-effect-update/. There are few apps who do that on iPhone like one here:  www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvCHHUN8nnE

I am wondering how do they perform this.

I am trying to use displacement map based technique describe here:  www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/11659 but it seems to be slow to be done on the fly.

Any pointer would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way to achieve displacement mapping in OpenGL ES 2.0 is also probably the fastest. You need two textures, one to contain color (a regular one), and a displacement map. When sampling the regular texture normally, your fragment shader would look like:

```
uniform sampler2D myTexture;
varying vec2 texcoords;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(myTexture, texcoords);
}
```

This is pretty simple stuff. Now, to achieve displacement mapping, you need to:

```
uniform sampler2D myTexture;
uniform sampler2D myDisplacementMap;
varying vec2 texcoords;

void main()
{
    vec2 displacement = 0.1 * texture2D(myDisplacementMap, texcoords).rg;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(myTexture, texcoords + displacement);
}
```

This is also simple. You have another texture where red and green are used as x and y for the displacement. This way, however, you only get static, view-independent displacement. To get real displacement, one would need to [generate texture tangents and bitangents](http://www.terathon.com/code/tangent.html) which contain the directions of texture axes in object space (a tricky concept, read the article). Once you have them, all you need is object-space eye position (can be calculated by multiplying vertex position by modelview-projection inverse in vertex shader), and by projecting this on the tangent/bitangent vectors, you can modulate the displacement in order to be view dependent:

```
attribute vec3 position, tangent, bitangent;
attribute vec2 texcoord;
varying vec2 texcoords;
varying vec3 eye_dir, tan, bitan;
uniform matrix4f modelviewProjectionMatrix;
uniform matrix4f modelviewProjectionMatrixInverse;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = modelviewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    tan = tangent;
    bitan = bitangent;
    texcoords = texcoord;
}
```

(that was vertex shader), and fragment shader here:

```
uniform sampler2D myTexture;
uniform sampler2D myDisplacementMap;
varying vec2 texcoords;
varying vec3 eye_dir, tan, bitan;

void main()
{
    vec2 eyen = normalize(eye_dir);
    vec2 modulation = vec2(dot(eyen, normalize(tan)), dot(eyen, normalize(bitan)));
    vec2 displacement = 0.1 * texture2D(myDisplacementMap, texcoords).rg * modulation;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(myTexture, texcoords + displacement);
}
```

And that should do the trick ... (note i wrote that from head so if there are any errors, don't hesitate to comment)

**EDIT**: And there were errors, I swapped order of arguments to texture2D (sampler goes first).

Comment: I think your texture2D has it's params reversed (should be myDisplacementMap, texcoords).