# Displacement Map with OpenGL on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I am looking for any help with code samples or tutorials to implement displacement mapping on iPhone with `OpenGL`. Can you help me to get started on this?

Comment: A bit of a broad question, considering that you didn't even state if you use OpenGL ES 1 or 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displacement map based 3d effect on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768719/displacement-map-based-3d-effect-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

I am also exploring the possibility of implementing displacement mapping on iPhone using OpenGL ES! After 2 weeks of research and experiment,I want to say it's nearly impossible to achieve this on iOS5+ devices!
   You can download the powerful PowerVR Insider SDK v3.1 Mac version here:http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp, and try the "DisplacementMap" example(The cow face) in its Intermediate Example folder. Hope you can get the point.